# llply subset by a function applied to an element in the list

Tags: r, subset, plyr

I have a list that I am failing at subsetting. This is what the list looks like:

```
dune.envfit <- 
structure(list(vectors = structure(list(arrows = structure(c(0.280345610462046, 
0.23065528788472, -0.529798086330133, 0.143997109594625, -0.164377286767545, 
-0.135605646341866, -0.963240459395111, -0.317899182650768, 0.128920508855905, 
0.219446302740393, 0.716407585418307, 0.787931102449639, 0.346775848714473, 
-0.237555622845223, -0.436638573595095, -0.218629125777214, -0.316702141990071, 
0.0503363265919834, 0.959899129437392, 0.973035527702261, -0.848123804477229, 
0.989578108300903, -0.986397540343111, -0.990762892260406, -0.26864068452916, 
-0.948124522238495, 0.991654931110784, 0.975624579545622, -0.697681998875642, 
0.615763410566507, -0.937948032008361, -0.971373937294294, -0.899637013494243, 
-0.975808026899703, -0.948525040923486, 0.998732323610899), .Dim = c(18L, 
2L), .Dimnames = list(c("TIC.mg.L", "Alkalinity.mg.L", "TOC.mg.L", 
"DIC.mg.L", "DOC.mg.L", "Na", "K", "Mg", "Ca", "Dissolved.N.mg.L", 
"Total.N.mg.L", "SI75", "FI", "HIX", "BIX", "EX.max", "MAXI", 
"MaxEX"), c("MDS1", "MDS2")), decostand = "normalize"), r = structure(c(0.59685535501548, 
0.185756858794004, 0.774378247785189, 0.19777058682652, 0.773575290577961, 
0.355910385488688, 0.808105377304065, 0.757415261345049, 0.808139825741362, 
0.756826061659786, 0.766773822773421, 0.297255075467242, 0.0482776303145529, 
0.458034365410462, 0.533467657077853, 0.757925150420371, 0.757494019430756, 
0.452226922967628), .Names = c("TIC.mg.L", "Alkalinity.mg.L", 
"TOC.mg.L", "DIC.mg.L", "DOC.mg.L", "Na", "K", "Mg", "Ca", "Dissolved.N.mg.L", 
"Total.N.mg.L", "SI75", "FI", "HIX", "BIX", "EX.max", "MAXI", 
"MaxEX")), permutations = 999, pvals = c(0.014, 0.418, 0.003, 
0.367, 0.003, 0.1, 0.002, 0.003, 0.001, 0.003, 0.003, 0.158, 
0.836, 0.042, 0.02, 0.003, 0.003, 0.095)), .Names = c("arrows", 
"r", "permutations", "pvals"), class = "vectorfit"), factors = NULL, 
    na.action = function (object, ...) 
    UseMethod("na.action")), .Names = c("vectors", "factors", 
"na.action"), class = "envfit")
```

I would like to pull out every element in the list that is tied to any pvals<0.05. I know the pvals are somewhere in the first element of the list.  They are the column named Pr(>r),even though in the str() of the list they are called pvals:

```
> dune.envfit[[1]]
                     MDS1     MDS2     r2 Pr(>r)    
TIC.mg.L          0.99242 -0.12290 0.5970  0.017 *  
Alkalinity.mg.L   0.91283  0.40833 0.1860  0.414    
TOC.mg.L         -0.55732  0.83030 0.7743  0.005 ** 
DIC.mg.L          0.42268  0.90628 0.1972  0.394    
DOC.mg.L         -0.52551 -0.85079 0.7742  0.003 ** 
Na               -0.38616 -0.92243 0.3543  0.096 .  
K                -0.36924  0.92934 0.8080  0.001 ***
Mg               -0.91182  0.41058 0.7574  0.004 ** 
Ca                0.35178  0.93608 0.8076  0.001 ***
Dissolved.N.mg.L  0.86231  0.50638 0.7572  0.003 ** 
Total.N.mg.L      0.26924 -0.96307 0.7671  0.005 ** 
SI75              0.41623 -0.90926 0.2971  0.165    
FI                0.18448 -0.98284 0.0486  0.824    
HIX              -0.95753 -0.28834 0.4569  0.056 .  
BIX              -0.65163  0.75853 0.5327  0.027 *  
EX.max           -0.86522 -0.50139 0.7572  0.006 ** 
MAXI             -0.91477  0.40398 0.7571  0.006 ** 
MaxEX             0.11461  0.99341 0.4542  0.070 .  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
P values based on 999 permutations.
```

So far I have been trying to apply llply as so:

```
dune.envfit<-llply(dune.envfit, dune.envfit$vectors$pvals, summarize,  function(x) x<0.05)
```

But this is not working with an error "Error in llply(dune.envfit, dune.envfit$vectors$pvals, summarize, function(x) x <  : 
  .fun is not a function." I do not know how to write a function for the purposes of llply type functions, and I believe the error is telling me that.

Thank you.

After discussing some possibilities, I now have only the pvals I want. However, I need to know what the name of the new list is that contains these pvals for later coding.

```
str(dune.envfit_subset)
List of 2
 $ : num [1:12, 1:2] 0.1125 -0.2401 -0.0644 -0.7822 -0.1268 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:12] "TIC.mg.L" "TOC.mg.L" "DOC.mg.L" "K" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "MDS1" "MDS2"
 $ :List of 3
  ..$ r           : Named num [1:12] 0.597 0.774 0.774 0.808 0.759 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:12] "TIC.mg.L" "TOC.mg.L" "DOC.mg.L" "K" ...
  ..$ permutations: num [1:12] 999 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ pvals       : num [1:12] 0.024 0.002 0.002 0.002 0.004 0.004 0.005 0.005 0.044 0.029 ...
```

Comment: Do you want something like `dune.envfit$vectors$arrows[dune.envfit$vectors$pvals>0.05,]` ?

Comment: That seems to return only the first element of the dune.envfit list. Is there any way to keep all of the other elements in the list as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want to subset all the values such that the associated p-value is less than 0.05.

Give this a try.

```
> dv <- dune.envfit$vectors
> dvSubset <- c(arrows = list(dv$arrows[w <- which(dv$pvals < 0.05),]), 
                lapply(dv[-1], `[`, w))
```

It looks like you could also do

```
> as.data.frame(dvSubset)[-4]
```

which returns a data frame of the desired subsets with the `permutations` column removed

```
> str(dvSubset)
List of 4
 $ arrows      : num [1:12, 1:2] 0.28 -0.53 -0.164 -0.963 -0.318 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:12] "TIC.mg.L" "TOC.mg.L" "DOC.mg.L" "K" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "MDS1" "MDS2"
 $ r           : Named num [1:12] 0.597 0.774 0.774 0.808 0.757 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:12] "TIC.mg.L" "TOC.mg.L" "DOC.mg.L" "K" ...
 $ permutations: num [1:12] 999 NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ pvals       : num [1:12] 0.014 0.003 0.003 0.002 0.003 0.001 0.003 0.003 0.042 0.02 ...
```

Comment: @user1757122 -  Cheers.  We can clean up these comments when you get a chance